# After setting custom UICollectionViewCell.contentview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, autolayout is not working

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

1. I made a custom collectionview cell in storyboard.
2. I added a button to collectionview cell, and set autolayout (0,0,0,0) to cell.
3. I made a custom collectionviewcell class. At this class, I set cell's contentview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
4. Cell's button's autolayout is not working!

   ```
   class SomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {    
      override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
      }


      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
      }

      func setup() {
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      }

   }
   ```

[code of ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLwLG.png)

[layout in StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIlQ0.png)

[Simulator: Button's autolayout is missed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBmwM.png)

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. It's hard to help you out when your question consists of one sentence. Thanks.

Comment: @dfd I pressed enter key by mistake while writing a question. I edited question with more detail situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at all constraints during runtime, and compared when translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is set to false and true. 
The result is that the cell's content view is not getting their height and width autolayout constraint when translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is set to false. In your case, this leads to [ambiguous layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AmbiguousLayouts.html)

As to why this is the case, I'm guessing that implementation of UICollectionFlowLayout relies on that property being set to true, but I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) As you mentioned, after setting contentview.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraint = false, the contentView’s constraints become ambiguous, and the subview’s (in this case the UIButton) autolayout also become ambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide a size for the cell in your delegate, by overriding the method `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview

UICollectionView is highly based on precise frame calculations hence your trouble with your constraints. You can setup constraints within the cell just fine, but you need to provide a size for the cell, unlike with UITableView.

Comment: That is not completely true. If you are using autolayout you can provide your collectionViewLayout with just estimated size and let the autolayout do its magic.